# Invalid radix-10 number index while generating route in flutter

Tags: flutter

while I was trying to generate page route using onGenerateRouter, I was getting "Invalid radix-10 numberindex" error

page url : /offer/3

```
onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings){
      if(!_isAuthorized){
        return MaterialPageRoute<bool>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Login()
        );
      }
      final List<String> pathElements = settings.name.split('/');
      if(pathElements[0] !='') {
        return null;
      }
      if(pathElements[1] == 'offer') {
        final int offerId = int.parse(pathElements[2]);
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => OfferDetailsPage(offerId)
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more context. Why do you think the error comes from this code. Please provide the full error output (stack trace). What device/emulator did you run the code on? What Flutter version are you using?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, thanks for the suggestion . I'm new to flutter development. 
I got the issue when I tried to navigate to details page. So thought that error might be in route generation. I just struggled in passing value to url. Finally sorted my issue .

Answer (score 0):

"Invalid radix-10 number" errors are usually thrown by FormatException. Check the value being formatted by `int.parse(pathElements[2]);` and see if it's a valid integer.